# Importing google jars into maven project

Tags: java, maven, youtube, pom.xml

I've been trying to add jars from google repositoroy to my project through Maven.
I cannot find the repository url which I could include in my pom.xml.
Does anyone know what the repository URL is? And if it exists at all?
This is the list of jars I'm trying to add.

```
gdata-analytics-2.1.jar
gdata-client-1.0.jar
gdata-gtt-2.0.jar
gdata-sidewiki-2.0.jar
gdata-analytics-meta-2.1.jar
gdata-client-meta-1.0.jar
gdata-gtt-meta-2.0.jar
gdata-sidewiki-meta-2.0.jar
gdata-appsforyourdomain-1.0.jar
gdata-codesearch-2.0.jar
gdata-health-2.0.jar
gdata-sites-2.0.jar
gdata-appsforyourdomain-meta-1.0.jar
gdata-codesearch-meta-2.0.jar
gdata-health-meta-2.0.jar
gdata-sites-meta-2.0.jar
gdata-base-1.0.jar
gdata-contacts-3.0.jar
gdata-maps-2.0.jar
gdata-spreadsheet-3.0.jar
gdata-blogger-2.0.jar
gdata-contacts-meta-3.0.jar
gdata-maps-meta-2.0.jar
gdata-spreadsheet-meta-3.0.jar
gdata-blogger-meta-2.0.jar
gdata-core-1.0.jar
gdata-media-1.0.jar
gdata-webmastertools-2.0.jar
gdata-books-1.0.jar
gdata-docs-3.0.jar
gdata-photos-2.0.jar
gdata-webmastertools-meta-2.0.jar
gdata-books-meta-1.0.jar
gdata-docs-meta-3.0.jar
gdata-photos-meta-2.0.jar
gdata-youtube-2.0.jar
gdata-calendar-2.0.jar
gdata-finance-2.0.jar
gdata-projecthosting-2.1.jar
gdata-youtube-meta-2.0.jar
gdata-calendar-meta-2.0.jar
gdata-finance-meta-2.0.jar
guava-14.0.1.jar
gdata-projecthosting-meta-2.1.jar
javamail-1.4.7/mail.jar
javamail-1.4.7/lib/mailapi.jar
javamail-1.4.7/dsn.jar
javamail-1.4.7/lib/gimap.jar
javamail-1.4.7/lib/pop3.jar
javamail-1.4.7/smtp.jar
```

Big Thanks,
Luke.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found the following in the  [Google APIs Client Library for Java](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/APIs#Google_Data_APIs) project

> We do not provide service-specific libraries for the Google Data APIs because they are built on an older infrastructure that does not have a Discovery Service. Nevertheless, the base Google API Client Library for Java fully supports Google Data APIs as long as you write your own Atom XML data model. Please take a look at the following examples for typical usage.....

Perhaps switching API is the best way forward as these libraries are all Mavenized and available in [Maven Central](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cg%3a%22com.google.apis%22)

Answer (score 3):

Switching to supported libraries would be the best option by **far**. However, if you *have* to use these, consider [Google Data APIs Mavenized](https://github.com/dcarter/Google-Data-APIs-Mavenized) which will generate poms for these libraries that you can deploy to your own repository, or [Mandubian MVN](http://code.google.com/p/mandubian-mvn/) which appears to have hosted these jars with Google Code as a Maven repository.

Answer (score 0):

burtsev-net-maven
      Burtsev.Net Maven Repository
      http://maven.burtsev.net

This has all the required dependencies. We used it in out company

http://tech.gozoomo.com/getting-started-with-google-spreadheet-api-and-oauth2/